# how to recursively delete all nodes in JTree?

Tags: java, swing, jtree, treemodel

in a `JTree` comprised of `DefaultMutableTreeNodes`, how would you traverse and delete starting from a given Node and all it's ancestors?

it should delete starting at it's deepest level , backing upwards to the given Node. the given starting node should be the last thing to remove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursion is your friend here.

In pseudo code:

```
def deleteTree(root)
    for each child c of root
        deleteTree(c)
    end
    delete root
end
```